# Node.js, ws-tcp-relay with nats: connection error

Tags: node.js, tcp, websocket, nats.io

Please help solve the problem:

When I start the nats server listening 4222 port:
`./gnatsd --addr localhost --port 4222`, then 
`./ws-tcp-relay localhost:4222 -p 4223` and try to connect through websockets using websocket-nats like this (in service.js for example):

```
'use strict';
const nats = require('websocket-nats').connect('ws://localhost:4223');
```

I get this error:

```
node server.js 
events.js:188
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Unhandled "error" event. (Could not connect to server: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:4223 localhost:4223:4223)
    at Client.emit (events.js:186:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dev/projects/node-pub/node_modules/websocket-nats/lib/nats.js:404:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

But, if I try to connect to nats directly using tcp client port 4222, the connection establishes succesfull:

```
const nats = require('nats').connect('nats://localhost:4222');
```